Skipping lines w/out data
I have a list of data:

I wrote a script that will move that data into my database placing the date in the appropriate column after finding the row with the person's name.  I would like to adjust my script so that it skips any rows that don't have a date in the 3rd column. In my above example it would update Brad & Chris' records, skip Dana update David, skip Gabi and update Jacob.
As I've written it now the program takes about 20 seconds per record to search the existing database before adding the date. Since the list usually includes 40-50 names with only 4 or 5 having dates with them if I could make it skip empty rows that could reduce the runtime of my script.
Below is my script as it stands now - this works but as mentioned above it looks up every name on the list in my database and takes 5+ minutes to run.
function datesFASigned() {
      var data4RUSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Set variable for Google Sheet
      var shDates = data4RUSS.getSheetByName("Live to RUSS"); //Set variable for Franchise Data
      var listLength = shDates.getRange("J4").getValue(); // Set variable for length of FDD list
      let listRange = shDates.getSheetValues(4,5,listLength,3); // Set range for Can Sign FA List

      var toRUSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1H--DhiSVjDnhVV8xYCD-H1QJOrTcML33GG05nzrAXN0");
      var dataEntry = toRUSS.getSheetByName("Data Entry"); //Data Entry tab on RUSS
  

    for (var a = 5; a <= listLength+4; a++) //formula to advance through class roster
    {
       var PPAD       = shDates.getRange(a,9).getValue(); //Set variable for Emp roster 
       console.log(PPAD);
       var values = dataEntry.getDataRange().getValues(); //getting the entire values from Emp Data    range and assigning it to values variable
    

        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) // formula to search Emp Data for Emp Name in column CP
     {
       var rowValue = values[i]; // declaring the data row as a variable

       //checking the first value of the record is equal to search item
        if (rowValue[0] == PPAD) {

         var  iRow = i+1; //identify the row number
         console.log(iRow)
 
         dataEntry.getRange(iRow, 43).setValue(shDates.getRange(a,12).getValue()); //Date ppAD  Signed FA

       valuesFound=true;


          }

      }

    }

    }


try:
function datesFASigned() {
  var data4RUSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Set variable for Google Sheet
  var shDates = data4RUSS.getSheetByName("Live to RUSS"); // Set variable for Franchise Data
  var listLength = shDates.getRange("J4").getValue(); // Set variable for length of FDD list
  let listRange = shDates.getSheetValues(4, 5, listLength, 3); // Set range for Can Sign FA List

  var toRUSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1H--DhiSVjDnhVV8xYCD-H1QJOrTcML33GG05nzrAXN0");
  var dataEntry = toRUSS.getSheetByName("Data Entry"); // Data Entry tab on RUSS

  for (var a = 5; a <= listLength + 4; a++) { // Formula to advance through class roster
    var PPAD = shDates.getRange(a, 9).getValue(); // Set variable for Emp roster 
    var dateInG = shDates.getRange(a, 7).getValue(); // Get the value in the G column

    // Skip the row if the G column is empty
    if (!dateInG) {
      continue;
    }

    console.log(PPAD);
    var values = dataEntry.getDataRange().getValues(); // Getting the entire values from Emp Data range and assigning it to values variable

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { // Formula to search Emp Data for Emp Name in column CP
      var rowValue = values[i]; // Declaring the data row as a variable

      // Checking the first value of the record is equal to search item
      if (rowValue[0] == PPAD) {
        var iRow = i + 1; // Identify the row number
        console.log(iRow);

        dataEntry.getRange(iRow, 43).setValue(shDates.getRange(a, 12).getValue()); // Date ppAD Signed FA
      }
    }
  }
}


modification ensures that the script processes and exports data only for rows where the G column is not empty, effectively skipping rows that do not have a date in the column G


Thank you this did EXACTLY what I needed it to and was really easy to deploy!

Try this:
let listRange = shDates.getSheetValues(3,5,listLength,4).getValues().filter(r => r[0]).map((([a,b,c,d]) => [b,c,d]));


ArrayLiteralAssignment
Array.methods()

